# Android hybrid app not working with SHA2 certificates

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, ssl-certificate, sha2

I have a hybrid Android app that uses a number WebView controls to display HTML content. From the HTML I've calling APIs via jQuery using HTTPS. Everything has been working fine with the certificates configured to use SHA1 but now that the servers have been updated to use SHA2, the app is not working anymore when making requests to API. According to this link: https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-compatibility.htm, SHA2 should be compatible with Android 2.3+ and I've been testing with Android 4.0+ so not sure what the issue is.

To test, I was able to have the certificate reverted to SHA1 and the app works again, but cannot leave it like that.

Thanks.

Comment: I just ran into this issue with a salesforce integration with a cordova app on android 4.2.2.  I believe the webview does not support sha256 cert.
Salesforce provides a test page to see if you browser supports sha256 https://sha2test.force.com/ .   The default browser for android 4.2.2 fails this test.